# Why i cant use StringBuilder::reverse in as method reference to reverse a string?

Tags: java, method-reference

Why i cant use StringBuilder::reverse in as method reference to reverse a string?
please help make me understand whats going on under the hood.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        String[] names = {
                "MEmarGya", "KaandHoGYa",
                "lmaodEd", "OmFOOF",
                "lakshayGulatiOP", "deEpAkKaLaL"
        };

        List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(names);

        ArrayList<UnaryOperator<String>> operators = new ArrayList<>();
        operators.add(s -> s.toUpperCase());
        operators.add(String::toUpperCase);

        operators.add(s -> s + s.charAt(random.nextInt(0, s.length())));

        operators.add(s -> s + ' ' + new StringBuilder(s).reverse());
        operators.add(StringBuilder::reverse); //<------ Here

        for (UnaryOperator<String> operator: operators) {
            namesList.replaceAll(operator);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));

        }


    }
}
```

err occured:

java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
method reverse in class java.lang.StringBuilder cannot be applied to given types
required: no arguments
found:    java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: `StringBuilder::reverse` is not a *function that takes and returns a string*. So why would you expect it to be usable as a `UnaryOperator<String>`?

Comment: And from an intuitive perspective, `reverse` is not a method of `String` ... so why would you can call it on a `String` object ... by any means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add [`UnaryOperator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) instances to the `operators` [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html). This means you need a method that accepts a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) and returns a `String`.

But you try to add the method reference - [`StringBuilder::reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) - which is a method that accepts a `StringBuilder` and returns a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and therefore conforms with `UnaryOperator<StringBuilder>`.

You can still use that method with a lambda expression, that will accept a `String`, convert it to `StringBuilder`, reverse it, and convert back to `String`:

```
operators.add(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse ().toString ());
```